# How to change url in html parser

Tags: php, dom

I have this code that output all url with `?tid=someNumbers`

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://news.sinchew.com.my/node');


// Find all links 
foreach($html->find('a') as $element) {
       $tid = '?tid';
       $url = 'news.sinchew.com.my/node';
       if(strpos($element->href,$tid) && (strpos($element->href,$url))) {
           echo $element->href . '<br>';
       }
}
?>
```

What i wanted to do is change `?tid=someNumbers` to `?tid=1234` and then output all url with `?tid=1234` . I stuck here for hours,can someone help me with this?

Comment: what criteria does the href attribute have to meet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `preg_replace` to perform substitutions based on regular expressions:

```
<?php

//...

echo preg_replace("/\\?tid=[0-9]+/", "?tid=1234", $element->href);

//...

?>
```

Comment: thanx ! all url have tid=1234. :)